# Python multiprocessing (pool map) freezing

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-requests

multi() freezes somewhere in the middle of its activity:

```
def current_proc(): print mp.current_process().name, 'started'

def multi(fn, func):
   print 'Process started on',time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

   count = mp.cpu_count()*2
   input = nohead(xlsx2array(fn))
   parts = chunks(input, 10)

   pool = mp.Pool(processes = count, initializer = current_proc, maxtasksperchild = 1)
   for part in parts:
       with stopwatch() as r: pool.map(func, part)

   return r
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
```

I am using multiprocessing with the function to get effective urls:

```
def query(i):
    attempts = 2
    while attempts:
        try:
            q = requests.get(i, allow_redirects = True, verify = False, timeout = 2)
            match = q.url                                                                                         
            match = str(match)
            break
        except:
            attempts -= 1
            match = 'pattern not found'
            pass

    return [ i, match ]
```

Please advise how can I avoid such freezing. Thanks,

Comment: Can you be more specific about where its freezing? It is in the middle of `query` somewhere, or is the `map` command frozen even though all instances of `query` have completed?

Comment: `somewhere in the middle of its activity` Is it soo difficult to debug it and check where exactly?

Comment: use `for i, _ in enumerate(pool.imap_unordered(func, (job for part in parts for job in part))): print(i)` to track progress